# Error while encoding the floating point numbers by embedding layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning, data-science

I have an excel file with floating point features and I am using embedding layer to encode those floating point numbers and it is giving me following error.

Input an excel file which has floating point numbers

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(20000, 5, input_length=160))
```

> Error:
> InvalidArgumentError:  indices[189,146] = -1 is not in [0, 20000)